# Python API Monitoring manager

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have been checking the Python API and its managers. However, I did not see an option / a manager to address the monitoring side.

Can you please tell me if there is such an option (viewing alerts / customizing thresholds / viewing graphs in CSV format) for the Python API?

Thank you!

Comment: This is a better question/feature request for the project's github issues page: https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/issues.

Answer (score 1):

there is no manager for monitoring agents, you have to use simple API calls. Here some examples:

```
"""
Configure the section 'CPU' from the 'Cpu, Disk, and Memory Monitoring Agent' agent.

Important manual pages
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/findByIpAddress
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/findByIpAddress
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Monitoring_Agent/applyConfigurationValues
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Monitoring_Agent_Configuration_Value

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""

import SoftLayer
import json

# The IP address of the server or VSI to configure.
ipAddres = "159.8.52.188"

configuration = {
    'Graph System CPU Usage': "False",
    'Graph Total CPU Usage': "False",
    'Graph User CPU Usage': "True",
    'Graph I/O Wait CPU Usage': "True",
    'Processor Queue Length Alarm': "True",
    'CPU Usage Error Alarm': "True",
    'CPU Usage Error Alarm Threshold': "99",
    'CPU Usage Warning Alarm': "True",
    'CPU Usage Warning Alarm Threshold': "82",
    'Processor Queue Length Alarm': "True",
    'Max Queue Length': "4"
}

# The agent's name we wish to configure.
agentName = 'Cpu, Disk, and Memory Monitoring Agent'

client = SoftLayer.Client()
vsiService = client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest']
hardwareService = client['SoftLayer_Hardware_Server']
monitoringService = client['SoftLayer_Monitoring_Agent']

# Getting the monitoring agents installed in the server or VSI.
try:
    objectMask = 'mask[monitoringAgents[configurationValues[definition]]]'
    server = vsiService.findByIpAddress(ipAddres, mask=objectMask)
    if not 'id' in server:
        server = hardwareService.findByIpAddress(ipAddres, mask=objectMask)
        if not 'id' in server:
            print("There is no a Server or VSI with the IP address: " + ipAddres)
            exit(1)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to get the server "
          % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)

# Getting the agent to configure.
agents = [agent for agent in server['monitoringAgents'] if agent['name'] == agentName]
if len(agents) == 0:
    print("Unable to find the agent: " + agentName)
    exit(1)
agent = agents[0]

# Creating an SoftLayer_Monitoring_Agent_Configuration_Value skeleton
# which contains the configuration for the agent.
configurationValues = []
for item in configuration.keys():
    itemFound = False
    for value in agent['configurationValues']:
        if value['definition']['name'].strip().upper() == item.strip().upper():
            itemFound = True
            configurationValue = value
            configurationValue['value'] = configuration[item].strip().upper()
            configurationValues.append(configurationValue)
            break
    if not itemFound:
        print("The configuration: " + item + " is not available for the agent.")


# Calling the SoftLayer_Monitoring_Agent::applyConfigurationValues method
# to apply the changes in the agent.
# Note: In case there is no changes in the agent configuration the method
# will return error.
try:
    result = monitoringService.applyConfigurationValues(configurationValues, id=agent['id'])
    print(json.dumps(result, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')))
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to apply the configuration in the monitoring agent."
          % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)
```

--

```
"""
Get the configuration of the monitoring agent in a server or VSI.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/findByIpAddress
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/findByIpAddress
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Monitoring_Agent/
http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Object-Masks

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""

import SoftLayer
import json

ipAddres = "169.54.54.164"

client = SoftLayer.Client()
vsiService = client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest']
hardwareService = client['SoftLayer_Hardware_Server']

try:
    objectMask = 'mask[monitoringAgents[configurationTemplate[configurationSections[subSections]],' \
                 'configurationValues[id, value, profileId, agentId, configurationDefinitionId,' \
                 'profile, definition[attributes, section, valueType]]]]'
    server = vsiService.findByIpAddress(ipAddres, mask=objectMask)
    if not 'id' in server:
        server = hardwareService.findByIpAddress(ipAddres, mask=objectMask)
        if not 'id' in server:
            print("There is no a Server or VSI with the IP address: " + ipAddres)
            exit(1)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to get the server "
          % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)

# We will get the configuration of the active agents
agents = [agent for agent in server['monitoringAgents'] if agent['statusName'] == "Active"]
server['monitoringAgents'] = agents

configs = []
for agent in server['monitoringAgents']:
    config = {}
    config['agent'] = agent['name']
    config['id'] = agent['id']
    sections = []
    for section in agent['configurationTemplate']['configurationSections']:
        sect = {}
        subsects = []
        hasProfile = False
        profileIds = []
        confs = []
        for subsection in section['subSections']:
            values = [value for value in agent['configurationValues'] if
                      value['definition']['sectionId'] == subsection['id']]
            for value in values:
                conf = {}
                if value['profileId'] == "":
                    conf[value['definition']['name']] = value['value']
                    confs.append(conf)
                else:
                    hasProfile = True
                    profileIds.append(value['profileId'])      
        sect['name'] = section['name']
        if not hasProfile:
            sect['configuration'] = confs
            sections.append(sect)
        else:
            profileIds = list(set(profileIds))
            profiles = []
            for profileId in profileIds:
                profile = {}
                valueConfs = []
                valueProfiles = [value for value in agent['configurationValues'] if
                                 value['profileId'] == profileId]
                profile['name'] = valueProfiles[0]['profile']['name']
                for valueProfile in valueProfiles:
                    value = {}
                    value[valueProfile['definition']['name']] = valueProfile['value']
                    valueConfs.append(value)
                profile['configuration'] = valueConfs
                profiles.append(profile)
            sect['profiles'] = profiles
            sections.append(sect)
    config['sections'] = sections
    configs.append(config)
print(json.dumps(configs, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')))
```

--

```
"""
View the reports for the  "CPU" section from the
'Cpu, Disk, and Memory Monitoring Agent' monitor agent.

Important manual pages
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/findByIpAddress
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server/findByIpAddress
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Monitoring_Agent/getGraphData
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/Monitoring_Agent_Configuration_Value/getMetricDataType

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""

import SoftLayer
import json

# The IP address of the server or VSI to configure.
ipAddres = "159.8.52.188"

startDate = '2016-01-02'
endDate = '2016-01-08'

# Set "True" the reports you wish to see.
reports = {
    'Graph System CPU Usage': "False",
    'Graph Total CPU Usage': "False",
    'Graph User CPU Usage': "False",
    'Graph I/O Wait CPU Usage': "True",
}

# The agent's name we wish to see the reports.
agentName = 'Cpu, Disk, and Memory Monitoring Agent'

client = SoftLayer.Client()
vsiService = client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest']
hardwareService = client['SoftLayer_Hardware_Server']
monitoringService = client['SoftLayer_Monitoring_Agent']
agentConfigurationService = client['Monitoring_Agent_Configuration_Value']

# Getting the monitoring agents installed in the server or VSI.
try:
    # Setting an object mask to retrieve information about the monitoring agents.
    objectMask = 'mask[monitoringAgents[configurationValues[definition]]]'
    server = vsiService.findByIpAddress(ipAddres, mask=objectMask)
    if not 'id' in server:
        server = hardwareService.findByIpAddress(ipAddres, mask=objectMask)
        if not 'id' in server:
            print("There is no a Server or VSI with the IP address: " + ipAddres)
            exit(1)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to get the server "
          % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)

# Getting the agent to see the reports.
agents = [agent for agent in server['monitoringAgents'] if agent['name'] == agentName]
if len(agents) == 0:
    print("Unable to find the agent: " + agentName)
    exit(1)
agent = agents[0]

# Creating the list of SoftLayer_Container_Metric_Data_Type objects
metricDataTypes = []
for item in reports.keys():
    if reports[item].strip().upper() == "TRUE":
        itemFound = False
        for value in agent['configurationValues']:
            if value['definition']['name'].strip().upper() == item.strip().upper():
                itemFound = True
                if value['value'].strip().upper() == "TRUE":
                    try:
                        metrics = agentConfigurationService.getMetricDataType(id=value['id'])
                        metricDataTypes.append(metrics)
                    except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
                        print("Unable to get the metrics. " % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
                else:
                    print("The report: " + item + " is disable for the agent. Please review the agent configuration.")
                    exit(1)
                break
        if not itemFound:
            print("The configuration: " + item + " is not available for the agent.")

# Getting the reports.
try:
    data = monitoringService.getGraphData(metricDataTypes, startDate, endDate, id=agent['id'])
    print(json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')))
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to get the report. "  % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

Comment: Hello,

Thank you so much for your fast response.
I will give it a try.

Have a great day!

Comment: I've added these examples to https://softlayer.github.io/python/monitoring/ thanks :)